# SharePoint designer workflow to manage list item permissions for employee/manager

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I used SharePoint Designer and created a workflow for a list and made some permissions. I want  to:

1. Give the the **manager** of every department permission to **view** the employee **item** in the list and **edit** it as well as
2. Allow the manager to make a new item
3. The **employees** should on be able to **create a new item and view his own items**

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to take care of :-

**Create Appropriate Permissions Levels and Groups**
   Make permission level say "Generic Edit" for Edit access which includes - Add , Edit , View no delete,no approve. Make another permission level say "Generic Add"  which includes - Add , no edit, Read , no delete , no approve.

Create groups for Managers and Employees and give them read access at the site level. At the list level give the Managers group "Generic Edit" rights and the Employees group "Generic Add".

**Create a list view.**
Create a list view for all employees and make it as the default view. On the view creation page , Select filter options and the field to filter should be "created by" and enter the value as "[me]" without the quotes. This will only show items that were created by the currently logged in user and not all the items in the list.

To show the managers all items in the list , create a page in the pages library and add the list to a webpart zone. Here you can create a view that shows all items and this view remains specific to the webpart. Grant the managers group read access on this page through 'manage permissions'.

This way , you can set two different views of a single list for two groups without using a workflow.

Comment: you are talking about the sharepoint not the workflow right ???

Comment: I am talking about permissions and list view for the list where your workflow is attached.

Comment: i did the 2 steps but this will make the every one can see items created by him even the managers and i want the manager to see all how can i do that ???

Comment: For that you can create a separate blank webpart page inside the pages library and insert the list as custom webpart inside a webpart zone. Give read access to the managers group on this page  and modify the view of the list to show all items without a filter on this page. This way managers can see all items while employees gets to see only their items.

Comment: but i need to do this stuff by using workflow

Comment: i created an "Impersonation Step" and inside it i wrote replace permission ( 1- manager groups full control and 2- employees view only ) - current item but this made the managers see and edit the list created by employees and employees can view only but what i couldn't do is to make the employees can the the items created by others ( employees and manager) , i mean i want the employee see only the items that created by him

but i don't know how to do this step in the workflow ??

Comment: Using designer based workflows I am not really sure if this is possible. Using a visual studio driven workflow you can achieve this once you get the list object. But question is why do you want to set the views through a workflow when sharepoint gives you the option of creating list views on the fly with your required security filters...

Comment: i created 2 view but i didn't know how to make one of them appear to managers and the other foe employees thats why i tried to do that by using the workflow if you know another way please tell me

Comment: The other way is what I have mentioned in my answer... :)

Comment: I have modified my answer to include more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

We can acive it using any one of below option

1. manage with workflow
   In codeplux we can download some workflow utility. In this utility we have the option to manage item level permision. Please see the link http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/
2. Create a new sharepoint group "managers" and in the list, give full privilage for managers and contribute permission for all employs. And in the advance settings of the list set view and edit only thir own items
3. Create visual studio workflow